# What is the best way to copy and compare data received from Web API request to SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, ssis, windows-services, data-migration

There is a requirement in my project where we need to design a system which can collect data through Web API and then use the data to compare and copy the received data to an existing SQL Server DB. I want to know if anyone has already worked on such requirement and if yes then what is the best way to design it? I am currently thinking of below two options. Please let me know which one is better and if there is any other option.

My algorithm will be as -  fetch the data through web api -> compare the data -> save mismatched data to a particular table -> copy new data to the existing tables.

The two options I am currently thinking of are-

1) Use a windows service which will run once in a day and execute above algo.

2) Use SSIS package which will run once in a day and execute above algo.

If anyone has used either of this solution, please guide me to an article or blog which can be helpful to me.

Comment: WEB api? return JSON component?

Comment: It will be JSON data

Comment: I will post my method below

Comment: Web API or the Web service will be exposed by the third party system.

Comment: @Long- Sure and Thanks for the help.

Comment: it does not matter, using webclint class to visit and get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar project requirement before. What I achieved is in SSIS.

Brief steps:

1. Using C# script to get the return data (http://json2csharp.com/ is an easy way to return C# class based on your JSON components)
   using third party dll, install Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the JSON
2. Assign the results in C# script to each pre defined variable (be careful with the data type)
3. Compare the result with the existing table in data flow task.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Is there any article or blog which describes the steps? I haven't worked on SSIS before. So need a good article which I can use to start with.

Comment: But thanks for the link you have given in the answer. That is really helpful.

Comment: Got this link which I think is helpful- http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.be/2013/05/using-json-feed-as-data-source-in-ssis.html. I will wait for few others to respond for any better solution before accepting your answer as my solution.

Comment: if you have any design issues, let me know or I could design the package for you